# How to make the that script repeat the command after 30 minutes without closing the cmd window?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
color A
ipconfig /release >NUL
echo Connection has been released! Refreshing connection...
ipconfig /renew >NUL
echo Connection established succesfully!
echo Press any key to quit...
pause >NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a batchfile wait for a timeout, using the `Timeout` command:

```
Prompt>timeout /t 3

Waiting for 3 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

The "3" changes into "2" into "1" into "0" and immediately goes to the next command (after all together 3 seconds). The maximum amount of seconds is 99999, and in half an hour (as you requested) there are only 1800 seconds.